# Saving redux store to localstorage - with lit-element

Tags: javascript, redux, local-storage, lit-element

Currently I'm trying to store a subset of my redux-state to localstorage. I was using the documentation from [PWA Starter Kit](https://pwa-starter-kit.polymer-project.org/redux-and-state-management#replicating-the-state-for-storage) to implement a basic storage, which works fine for now, but this only saves the complete state to the localstorage.

This isn't exactly what I want, because as mentioned, I only want to store a subset, like some specific action results (e.g. `state.settings` instead of `state`).

Every documentation and examples only store the complete state, I haven't found any comment that fits my need.

**My current implementation**

*redux-store.js*

```
import {
  createStore,
  applyMiddleware,
  compose as origCompose,
  combineReducers
} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { lazyReducerEnhancer } from 'pwa-helpers/lazy-reducer-enhancer';
import { loadState, saveState } from './redux-localstorage';

import applicationReducer from './reducers/application-reducer';

export const store = createStore(
  (state, action) => state,
  loadState(),
  compose(lazyReducerEnhancer(combineReducers), applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

export default store;

store.addReducers({
  applicationReducer
});

store.subscribe(() => {
  saveState(store.getState());
});
```

*redux-localstorage.js*

```
const STORAGE = '__RDX_STORAGE_TEST__';

export const saveState = state => {
  const json = localStorage.getItem(STORAGE) || '{}';
  const stringifiedNewState = JSON.stringify(state);

  if (stringifiedNewState !== json && stringifiedNewState !== '{}') {
    localStorage.setItem(STORAGE, stringifiedNewState);
  }
};

export const loadState = () => {
  const json = localStorage.getItem(STORAGE) || '{}';
  const state = JSON.parse(json);
  return state || undefined;
};
```

**So, my question is**: is this even possible? If yes, how can I achive this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: There may be a way to do this in an action creator or middleware, which only deals with that part of the state given to it by a reducer. I haven't tried either of these approaches so YMMV: https://daveceddia.com/access-redux-store-outside-react/

Comment: The simplest way I can think of is just destruct the state before saving and stringify only that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the basic PWA Starter Kit as a base, if for example you wanted to store the shop state and the counter state but not the app state, you could do something like this:

```js
const STORAGE = '__RDX_STORAGE_TEST__';

export const saveState = state => {
  const json = localStorage.getItem(STORAGE) || '{}';
  // take only the parts we need
  const {shop, counter} = state;
  const stringifiedNewState = JSON.stringify({shop, counter});

  if (stringifiedNewState !== json && stringifiedNewState !== '{}') {
    localStorage.setItem(STORAGE, stringifiedNewState);
  }
};

export const loadState = () => {
  const json = localStorage.getItem(STORAGE) || '{}';
  const state = JSON.parse(json);
  return state || undefined;
};
```

This way only those two sections will be written to localStorage

Comment: @sebastian what's the problem with loading?

Comment: Having some trouble injecting the saved data to the actual state and - if data is already in the storage - not to fetch the data again inside the action.

Comment: @sebastian you mean you want to merge both the current state with the one coming from localstorage?

Comment: yes, exactly that scenario. Let's say I have an action that get's dispatched every time the page loads. I need to check, if there's something already in localStorage and if yes, no new data should be fetched.

Comment: Can't you just add an if to check that?

Comment: Not sure if I'm using `loadState()` correct. It's used in `createStore()`, but if I `console.log` the `state` inside the dispatched action, de data from localStorage isn't listed there.

Comment: I'm using `getState()` inside my action to check the current store, but the data from the localStorage isn't present there, even though I'm using `loadState()` in the `createStore()` method... do you have any ideas?

Comment: Without being able to run the whole code, all I can think of if either the data wasn't in the localstorage so it wasn't loaded or it has something to do with the store's structure as the definition of the second argument of the createStore function seems to mention something like that https://redux.js.org/api/createstore#arguments

Comment: If I just put in the "whole" state (not only parts), it's there when loading the page. But as I write this, it makes sense, that there's no reducer for only the parts, so I should attach it to the corresponding reducer, I think... Thanks!